# Return Multiple Columns in Linq to Sql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

How do I return multiple columns with linq to sql in C#?

I tried to end my query with

```
select new { A.Product, A.Qty };
```

but this returns some anonymous type and I am not sure what the heck what to do with this, How to return it and how to extract information out of it. I want to put it in some sort of array.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying to return the data from a method?

If so, you should just end the query with `select A`, which will produce the same type that `A` is.

If not, you can use the anonymous type the same way you use a regular type.

For example:

```
var results = from ... select new { A.Product, A.Qty };

foreach(var thing in results) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", thing.Product, Thing.Qty);
}
```

**EDIT**: To make it into a list, call ToList, like this:

```
var resultsList = results.ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry I might have not been clear. I just those 2 columns. I thought maybe it is possible to do a query that gets those columns and makes it into a list.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "you should just end the query with select A, which will produce the same type that A is"?

Comment: @LoveDotNet: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I want to query only selected columns for performance reason, but return the original type from a method. Since this yields an anonymous type, I can't return it. Your comment sounds like a workaround for this problem. Is it?

Comment: @LoveDotNet: Then you can write `select new SomeType { X = a.X, Y = a.Y }`

Comment: @SLaks, this compiles just fine, but I get the following error: "Explicit construction of entity type *** in query is not allowed".

Comment: @LoveDotNet: I didn't know that. You can get around it by selecting an anonymous type, then calling `AsEnumerable()` and selecting `new SomeType` on the client.  (you'd have to copy each property twice)

Comment: @SLaks, could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Call tolist() on the query