# C# Linq-to-SQL multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am currently trying to select multiple columns in C# with Linq-to-SQL. When looking at other threads just as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885178/return-multiple-columns-in-linq-to-sql) it is a pretty simple thing to do, so I tried:

```
var users = context.GetTable<DbHelper.User>();

var query = from u in users
            where u.Email == TbUsername.Text
            select new { u.Active, u.Password };

if(!query.Any())
{
  MessageBox.Show("Could not find an account with that Email");
  return;
}

var result = query.First();   // Error occurs here
```

User table in `DbHelper`:

```
[Table(Name="Users")]
public class User 
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int Active { get; set; }
}
```

The table looks like this in SQL Server:

```
[ID]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[RoleID]    INT           NOT NULL,
[Email]     NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
[Password]  NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
[FirstName] NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
[LastName]  NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
[OfficeID]  INT           NULL,
[Birthdate] DATE          NULL,
[Active]    BIT           NULL,
```

Which results in an error

> System.InvalidCastException: The conversion is invalid

What is wrong with my code? It's really confusing since it seems to work for others. If you need more code please let me know

Comment: Do your class data types map to the correct corresponding sql types?

Comment: Yes they do except for Birthdate, because that is Date which does not exist in C# I believe. I can add the Database structure to the thread if that helps..?

Comment: Did you profile the actual sql query? What does it return?

Comment: If I understand you correctly it returned int: Active and string: Password BUT as Anonymours Types

Comment: I was asking if you profiled the actual sql call - using sql profiler.

Comment: OT both .Any() and .First() will cause a database query. You may want a .ToList() first and inspect the results from that

Comment: in which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I tried var list = query.ToList() which also resulted in an Invalid Cast Exception

Comment: @WilliamXifaras Haven't heard of that yet.. Really sorry but Iam completly new to this topic

Comment: Try changing the type of property Active to bool, as the column is a bit

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I actually can't believe I didn't see that... Changing to bool solved it. Now it's working as it should. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. If you post this as an answer I will instantly accept it as solved

Comment: @BenjaminFrost Seems your issue is resolved. Regardless, you should know how to profile and troubleshoot SQL calls. Will help in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the type of the Active column in your database table is 'bit', EF expects a property of type 'bool'. 
0==false, 1==true, as you might expect.

Comment: This is it.  Your data class doesn't match the underlying values.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.FirstOrDefault()` :

```
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

If the `result` is null after this call, then your selection just didn't return any rows from the database table.

Comment: Still the same error: Invalid Cast Exception. Iam also checking if the query finds any result, I should probably add it to the thread

Comment: First() throws ArgumentNullException in that case, not an InvalidCastException

Comment: @BenjaminFrost rather than checking ditectly right var result = query. FirstOrDefault() ;
Then go for checking is it null or not.

Comment: @DSPassionate check the updated Thread Iam checking using the query.Any() function